# Export Event with Attachment to outlook

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, outlook, office-integration

I am exporting SharePoint 2013 Calendar event from `custom command > Export event` to Outlook.

But the problem is that I want to export attachment along with event: By default it's exporting only event with their properties except attachment.

Can any one help me to export event with attachment in SharePoint 2013 calendar?

Answer (score 0):

That would involve a good amount of code and probably be easier to accomplish via a link to Exchange than through a calendar event created locally. It may be simpler to just use html in the calendar event description to link to the document stored on SharePoint.